# Product of two lists with rotation on only one list

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I want to obtain this is an output:

```
['xa' , 'yb' , 'zc']
['xb' , 'yc' , 'za']
['xc' , 'ya' , 'zb']
```

This is my attempt but it does not work:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['x','y','z']
size = len(list1)

for j in range(size):
    for i in range(size):
        n = list1[(i+j)%size]
        for k,l in enumerate(list2):
            list2[k] = list2[k] + n
        print(list2)
```

How can I obtain the desired output?

Comment: You want your output like this or with quotation marks? And what is the logic in the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want strings as output, you only need 2 nested loops, running over `i` and `j` up to `size`:

```
>>> [[list2[j] + list1[(i+j)%size] for j in range(size)] for i in range(size)]
[['xa', 'yb', 'zc'], ['xb', 'yc', 'za'], ['xc', 'ya', 'zb']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution without modulo

```
>>> [[elem2+elem1 for elem2,elem1 in zip(list2, list1[i:]+list1[:i])] for i in range(size)]
[['xa', 'yb', 'zc'], ['xb', 'yc', 'za'], ['xc', 'ya', 'zb']]
```